# Excel, Way to check if spreadsheets are identical?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 spreadsheets I want to get in sync. Is there a way to compare other then eye-test ? They are complex format with same formatting to cells. They are close I just want to confirm they are identical, few information in cells may be different.

Thanks

Comment: If some cells are different, then they are different; so a binary compare of the files wouldn't help.  You'll need to be much more specific about what you're trying to compare about workbooks/worksheets.

Comment: Sorry, typo lol. Same format is applied to cells of each sheet.

Comment: This is not possible to my knowledge. You may be able to write a macro, but it is likely going to take much more time to write the macro, than it is to manually compare it yourself.

Comment: I think you are right, its a big sheet and just want to make sure the text in some fields are identical.

Comment: Which version of excel? [Comparing Two Workbooks with Excel 2013's Compare Files Feature](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/722-tips-comparing-two-workbooks-excel2013-compare-files-feature)

Comment: got 2010, but may be able to get 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known good, and the 2nd sheet is identical with the possible exception of formatting. then

1. ctrl-a on good sheet to select all cells.
2. Ctrl-c to copy entire sheet
3. Go to sheet 2
4. paste special by using alt-e-s-t or using the paste special from the ribbon and select formats

Caveat- This may not work for active formatting.  Normal formatting and some conditional formatting will work ok. (Highlight any empty cells as yellow fill works. Highlight any number above MyGoal where MyGoal is a cell or equation may not come across correctly depending on details of how it is implemented.)

Comment: Its not so much the formatting, its comparing the texts in the cells to see if they match.

Comment: Do you mean, 1st sheet cell a3 = "RedRover" and 2nd sheet cell A3 = "NoGo" is what you are trying to locate?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to locate.

Comment: A straight forward way to do this is have the miss-compares have a conditional format that causes a yellow highlight. Then if no yellow = sheets are identical. However, that would scale well if you had a large amount of cells. Using VBA could help with scaling.  But might run into problems due to security and sharing rules.  If you do not have other macro based excel workbooks, it tends to be best to avoid macros.